# I am writing a function that takes as input several dictionaries and a dataframe and outputs a new dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe

I am writing a function that takes as input several dictionaries and a dataframe and outputs a new dataframe. I am getting an error before I can even test the function.

This is the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-29-52f796806c62>", line 34
    return df
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the code:

```
#define a function that takes a dict of client attributes,
#a df of provider data, a dictionary of weights,
#and outputs a data frame, showing how the top 50 relevant providers rank
#before and after the weights have been applied
#result set to look like df1=[[provider_id,baseline_score,rank_score]], 

client_1 = {'specialties': 'Big Box Retailer','county': 'San Francisco County'}
weights = {'self_performer': 10, 'decline_1':-5,'decline_2': -7.5,'decline_3': -10
,'industry':5,'unsat_demote_1': -5,'unsat_demote_2':-7.5,'scout':10}

def func(client_1=client_1, client_2=client_2,client_3=client_3, providers = providers, weights = weights):

    #create boosters based on pre-defined rules 
    df = providers

    #decline boosters
    df['rank_score']=np.where((df.percentage_declined_workorder>=0.05),df.rank_score+weights.decline_3,df.rank_score)
    df['rank_score']=np.where((df.percentage_declined_workorder < 0.05 &df.percentage_declined_workorder >= 0.03), df.rank_score+weights.decline_2,df.rank_score)
    df['rank_score']=np.where((df.percentage_declined_workorder < 0.03 &df.percentage_declined_workorder >= 0.02), df.rank_score+weights.decline_1,df.rank_score)

    #self_performer booster
    df['rank_score']=np.where((df.type == 'self-performer'),df.rank_score+weights.self-performer,df.rank_score)


    #recall boosters
    df['rank_score']=np.where((df.percentage_recalls_reopened>= 0.04),df.rank_score+weights.unsat_demote_2,df.rank_score)
    df['rank_score']=np.where((df.percentage_recalls_reopened>= 0.03 &df.percentage_recalls_reopened < 0.04), df.rank_score+weights.unsat_demote_1,df.rank_score)

    #SCOUT Provider boost
    df['rank_score']=np.where((df.is_scout_provider==1),df.rank_score+weights.scout,df.rank_score)


    #match client attributes
    #df1
    df1 = df[client_1.county in df.counties]
    df1 = df1[client_1.specialties in df1.specialties]
    df1 = df1[df1.trade==client_1.primary_trade]

    #specialties booster df1
    df1['rank_score']=np.where((client_1.specialties in df1.specialties),df1.rank_score+weights.specialties,df1.rank_score)

    #prep for output
    df1 = df1[['providers','baseline_score','rank_score']
              return df1
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a Square bracket here:

```
    df1 = df1[['providers','baseline_score','rank_score']**]**
          return df1
```

Also, you have unnecessary indentation at the function return.

its should be :

```
    #prep for output
    df1 = df1[['providers','baseline_score','rank_score']]
    return df1
```

Goodluck.